# What GPU component burned out?

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, nvidia-geforce

I've recently had two GPUs burn out at the same location on the PCB and am curious what the function is of this burned-out part. Here's a picture of the entire PCB:

[image: Burned PCB]

And here's another zoomed in at the specific part in question:

[image: Burned PCB Zoomed In]

I think these are surface mount capacitors between driver MOSFETs and the high/low MOSFETs. I also might be completely wrong. Are they? And what do they do? Is it common for these things to burn out?

Some other info:

- I believe the model is Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1080 Turbo OC 8G
- It occurred right as I turned on the computer. I could see an electrical arc flash momentarily before the typical electronics burning smell.
- They were properly installed without touching anything else.
- Environment is dry and cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a general pattern in how the components are laid out, and it's reasonably safe to say that the blown components are identical to the other ferrite beads above and below them.

Just to the right of that column are MOSFET driver chips. To the left of that column are two columns of power MOSFETs, then inductors and then filter capacitors. This is exactly the sort of pattern you'd expect to see for the various buck regulators that provide the various voltages that the GPU needs.

It's safe to say that the ferrite beads are filtering the inputs to these regulators, and it's probable that a failure in one of the regulators (or in whatever it is powering) caused the corresponding set of beads to fail.

Replacing the beads alone is probably NOT going to repair the board. It would require extensive reverse-engineering to find the root cause of the failure and correct it.

And unfortunately, this type of repair question is off-topic for EE.SE. Unless you can find someone who knows a lot about this specific board, it's probably junk at this point.

Comment: I don't think I would attempt to repair it, nor do I think that was the intent of the original question... What do you feel is the likely cause of this issue? Poor design of the board, poor quality components, or a bad power source?

Comment: @acejavelin: Again, that would require a great deal of reverse-engineering to even begin to answer a question like that. But if I had to guess, I would think that it's a load-side issue rather than a supply-side issue. It could be a design issue -- for example, improper power-up sequencing could be causing an unexpected load surge on one of the supply rails to the GPU chip. All just speculation, of course.